# discord.js V12 userinfo command with id

Tags: discord.js

Hey I'm currently working on something that you can do ,user  and it will show user info about that user.

```
if(args.length < 1) {
        var user = message.author;
    } else {
        var user = client.users.cache.get(args[0]);
    }

    if(!user || user == undefined) return message.channel.send("**Error:** An error occurred!");
```

But "user" is always undefined and I don't know why

Comment: what do you mean by `args[0]`. is it a pinged object or id of a user?

Comment: I think in the else part you want to find a mentioned user. For that, you have to use `message.mentions.user.first`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you would mention someone in that command. The reason this doesn't work is because `client.users.cache.get` doesn't take mentions, it only takes memberIDs.

What you should do instead is get the mention from the message. You do that by accessing the [`MessageMentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions) class.

```
message.mentions.members.first();
```

If you want/need to use IDs then your code will work. If you wish to use names you need to use the `find()` method.

```
client.users.cache.find(u => u.username === args.join(' '));
```

*Note: We `join(' ')` the args here to use it with multi-word names. Also note that the names only work if they are spelled correctly, meaning capitalization is important.*

Comment: though this certainly is useful information, i don't really think it answers the question of *why* user comes up with `undefined`. Of course, since he specified he is providing user ID i do not really think he is mentioning anyone. the problem is variable scope related.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should have been using `message.guild.members.cache` instead of `client.users.cache`. I've used the question mark operator here, this is how you use it:

```
condition ? value_if_condition_is_true : value_if_condition_is_false
```

I've also removed `user == undefined` as it does the exact same thing as `!user`

```
const memberMention = message.mentions.members.first();

var user = args[0] ? message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) : memberMention ? memberMention : message.author;

if (!user) return message.channel.send("**Error:** An error occurred!");
```

Comment: and why is this necessary? if `args[0]` returns a falsy value you can assume that they provided nothing, therefore `message.mentions.members.first()` will be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `user` is always undefined because you are calling it out of scope.

```js
if(args.length < 1) {
        var user = message.author; // the user variable is only valid in this "if" block
    } else {
        var user = client.users.cache.get(args[0]); // the user variable is only valid in this "else" block
    }

    if(!user || user == undefined) return message.channel.send("**Error:** An error occurred!");
```

Instead, you should include your code in the main `if-else` block or declare the `user` variable global by not using a variable declaration keyword.

```js
if(args.length < 1) {
        user = message.author; // the user variable is only valid in this "if" block
    } else {
        user = client.users.cache.get(args[0]); // the user variable is only valid in this "else" block
    }

    if(!user) return message.channel.send("**Error:** An error occurred!");
    console.log(user.tag)
    //further code here...
```

I've also cleaned up some redundancies for you: `if(!user)` will cover `undefined` as well, so no need to include `|| user == undefined`

Comment: to clarify: I want the player to enter a player id